# How to disable window resize on Flutter Desktop Windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, window-resize, flutter-desktop

When our Flutter desktop app running on Windows, if we resize the window or max the window, there will be a black area in the app. How to disable window resize on Flutter desktop windows?

I have tired

```
  ws.setWindowMaxSize(Size(width * 0.9, height * 0.9));
  ws.setWindowMinSize(Size(width * 0.9, height * 0.9));
```

But it does not work. There is no code to deal with the code 'setWindowMaxSize' and 'setWindowMinSize' in flutter-desktop-embedding\plugins\window_size\windows\window_size_plugin.cpp .

If it is difficult, is there any good idea to make the Flutter desktop app looks better when resizing? Maybe show a 'Loading' message? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this [Github post](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/testbed/lib/main.dart#L44-L55)?

Answer (score 0):

did you add this  to your pubspec?

```
window_size:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
      path: plugins/window_size
```

Comment: At the time the question was asked, window_size didn't support those methods on Windows; that was added several months later: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/pull/784